# Minimalist Web API Attribute Routing Setup - Help on Shared Hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, attributerouting

I have a SUPER simple Web API.  It is openly non-secure and simply provides free data.  I'd like to move it from my personal server to shared hosting (e.g.: GoDaddy), but I'm having issues.

There are a lot of similar questions relating to 404 status when attempting to access Attribute Routing Web API services on shared hosting solutions.  But none of them have worked for me.  This is my SUPER Simple current setup:

---

- Create a new .Net Framework 4.5 EMPTY C# Web Application named YourApplicationName
- Ensure all checkboxes and packages are NOT Checked
- Add a New "Global.asax" object
- Replace the entire contents of the C# with the following:

  ```
  using System.Web.Http;
  namespace YourApplicationName
  {
      public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
      {
          protected void Application_Start()
          {
              System.Web.Mvc.AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
              GlobalConfiguration.Configure((HttpConfiguration config) => { config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(); });
          }
      }

      public class TestController : System.Web.Http.ApiController
      {
          [System.Web.Http.Route("api/Test")]
          public string Get()
          {
              return "Test Info";
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Replace the Web.config file with the following:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <configuration>
    <system.web>
      <customErrors mode="Off" />
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
        <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
        <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
      </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
  </configuration>
  ```
- **Delete ALL** References other than System and System.Web
- PM> Install the following two packages:

Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc

Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost

---

With that, I can run in Dev, publish to my personal IIS, run on my company's IIS Servers, or even publish to azure (http://suamereapi.azurewebsites.net/api/Test) and if I navigate to the route, I appropriately get back "Test Info".

But when I publish to my shared hosting, I receive a 404 status.  **Note** that mvc controllers that return `Views` work just fine in the shared hosting, just not the `ApiControllers`.

Possible Issue 1 is that the IIS pipeline is not set up as Integrated on the hosted account.  Of course I have checked that mine is set to Integrated.

Possible Issue 2: Moreso related to API's **NOT** using Attribute Routing, is that the Register Routes needs to come before the GlobalConfiguration.  This is not applicable in a pure Attribute-Routing Web API setup.

Possible Issue 3: Some of the DLL's aren't in the shared hosting GAC, and also are not published from your local setup because they are not **Copy Local**.  I have altered Copy-Local to multiple setups from none, to just what is required, to all references.

Possible Issue 4: Shared hosting messes with the configuration paths because of virtual directories for subdomains or what not.  That is fixed by adding a `rewrite` to the Web.config as such:

```
rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="Remove Virtual Directory">
<match url=".*" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}" />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
```

Possible Issue 5: Some say to fix the issue you need to add `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"` and work with the httpHandlers to remove and manually add extension handlers, and UrlRoutingModules.

I have done all combinations of these workarounds, but I can't imagine what the true issue is.  Please let me know what I might be missing, I've spent days on this.

Comment: Does old-style route map work at all?

Comment: Yes.  If I add `config.Routes.MapHttpRoute` with a Name and routeTemplate, it works.  However, that is no longer using Attribute routing, and defeats the purpose.  But it is good added information for the question that it **does** work with traditional route configuration.  Just to be sure: the question is how to get Attribute Routing working with shared hosting, specifically GoDaddy.